# Are $p$-adic distance between points unique?

Tags: metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

The $p$-adic metric is defined on $\mathbb Q$ as follows:

$\rho(x,y)=p^{-\alpha}$ where $x-y={r\over s}p^{\alpha},gcd(r,s)=1,p\ $  is prime.

Now, if I take $x=10,y=4$ then $x-y=6=3.2$ Then what is $\rho (x,y)?$
By definition, both $1\over 2$ and $1\over 3$ qualify.

Is it fine for a metric to to give different values for the same two points?Don't the other metrics on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$ give unique value for same points.

Comment: The $p$-adic metric depends on the prime $p$. For example, the $3$-adic distance between $10$ and $4$ is $1/3$, while the $11$-adic distance is $1$. In other words, for every fixed prime $p$, you have a different $p$-adic metric on $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Crostul : Understood.

Comment: Your description of the $p$-adic metric is not correct. It’s $\rho(x,y)=p^{-a}$, no $r$ nor $s$ appearing in the formula.

Comment: @Lubin: edited.